# What is a wavefront algorithm?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, robotics

I am designing and researching algorithms which I call of a wavefront nature. It is image analsyis agorithms when every pixel may change many times during the processing. I have heard this name before, but it seems it is not used widely. Are there other "wavefront algorithms"?